# Samsung Smart TV App in eclipse

Tags: javascript, redirect, samsung-smart-tv, tvcontentitem

I'm developing an app for an Samsung Smart TV, and I need to redirect the tv content (TV channel) to a especifique position on the screen.

This is my code to resizing the tv content

```
var tvWindowObject = window.webapis.tv.window;

function resizeTvScreen(){
    tvWindowObject.getAvailableWindow(availableWindowSuccess, availableWindowFailure)
}

function availableWindowSuccess(){
    resizeTvWindowView();
}

var tvSpecs = {
    width : 400,
    height : 400,
    left : 0,
    bottom : 0
};
var sourceInfo = {
    type : tvWindowObject. SOURCE_MODE_TV,
    number : 0
}

function resizeTvWindowView(){
    var result = tvWindowObject.setRect(tvSpecs, 1);

   if(result == true){
      tvWindowObject.setSource(sourceInfo, setSourceSuccess, setSourceFailure);
   }else{
      alert('TV resize function failur');
   }
}
```

My problem is that the TV channel dose not resize. The TV content only shows in the desired position but the channel appears cut in the screen.

How can I redirect the TV channel window to my desired position?

Comment: Eclipse is just the IDE you are using and supports many different programming languages - which one is this?

Comment: I'm developing in JavaScript